# NestJS - typeorm - OneToOne onDelete CASCADE

Tags: typescript, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

For a project i need the OneToOne relationship of Typeorm.
This project is based on NestJS and Postgresql.

With the following two entities:

```
@Entity()
export class Order {
    @PrimaryColumn()
    id: number;

    @OneToOne(() => OrderPaymentDetails, { cascade: true, onDelete: 'CASCADE' })
    @JoinColumn()
    payment_details: OrderPaymentDetails
}
```

and

```
@Entity()
export class OrderPaymentDetails {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    description: string
}
```

**The desired behavior is as follows: When I delete an Order entity, I want the associated OrderPaymentDetails entity to be deleted too.**

When i save a command in the database, there is no problem, but when i delete an order, the associated OrderPaymentDetails is not deleted either.
If i go the other way and delete the OrderPaymentDetails, the associated order is deleted.

**What I tried:**

- I tried to put the onDelete: 'cascade' field on the OrderPaymentDetails entity.
- I tried with OneToMany, ManyToOne and ManyToMany relationships.
- I tried to add an Order field in the OrderPaymentDetails entity.

But none of these solutions work.
Does anyone have a solution for me ?

Thomas

Comment: in the first snippet you're saying: `once the parent is deleted, delete all of its children`. You could move the FK column to the other side instead to get what you want at database level. So try to move `@OneToOne` and `@JoinColumn` to `OrderPaymentDetails`

Comment: Did you find a solution yet? I think @MicaelLevi's solution is not really the best because it inverts the ownership of the relationship.